# AngularJS, Dropdpown set given boolean value as predefined text

Tags: angularjs, select

I have predefined scope values:

```
$scope.synchronizationStates =
                            [
                                true,
                                false
                            ];
```

And i have defined select:

```
<select class="form-control"  data-ng-model="projectDetail.synced" data-ng-options="synced for synchronizationState in projectDetail.synchronized">
</select>
```

I would like to have for state false display preselected value "NOT_SYNCED" and for true "SYNCED" And also change state value if value is changed by user.

How can I do it  please using AngularJs?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller use :

```
 $scope.synchronizationStates  = [
    {text:'not synced',value:false},
    {text:'synced',value:true},
    ]
```

and in html

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="value.value as value.text for value in synchronizationStates"></select>
```

working plunker here [a link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekTriQuZvH9h2Ft50HDi?p=preview)!

Answer (score 0):

I think its better for you to use something like this

```
    ng-options="e as e for e in synchronizationStates "></select>
```

and maybe make each element in the array an object with string for the name and true or false for the value